# Comparing dates to in if statement

Tags: php

My intended goal is to have it see if the post allows comments and if it does then check to make sure the date_comments_expires is NOT before the passed day. I'm not quite sure how to finish this if statement. Any help?

```
if ($mainNews[0]['allow_comments'] == 'Yes' AND $mainNews[0]['date_comments_expire'] == ) {
```

EDIT:

Here's my updated code in which I'm getting a call to member function getTimeStamp of non object

```
if ($mainNews[0]['allow_comments'] == 'Yes' AND $mainNews[0]['date_comments_expire']->getTimestamp() > time() ) {
                    echo "<a href=\"#\"></a><span>".$mainNews[0]['number_of_comments']."</span>";   
                }
```

Comment: do you miss something `] == )`?

Comment: @Book: I think that's the "I'm not quite sure how to finish this if statement" part, he doesn't know what to put after the last `==`.

Comment: What does `$mainNews[0]['date_comments_expire']` contain?

Comment: Is `date_comments_expire` a MySQL `DATE`-field?

Comment: date_comments_expire is a datetime field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends entirely on what is contained within the `date_comments_expire` index of your array. I would expect it to either be a unix timestamp stating when the comments expire, or a reasonable textual interpretation thereof.

If you're using a unix timestamp, then you're doing great. If it's text, then you're going to need to convert it into a unix timestamp before continuing. The best function for this is [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). It can parse a variety of textual datetime representations, and will return a unix timestamp as a result.

Once you have the endpoint represented as a timestamp, you can compare it against the current time. For this, you can use the [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function, which returns the current time as a unix timestamps.

Since unix timestamps are just integers (specifically, the number of seconds since Jan. 1, 1970), this is a simple comparison.

In the end, your code would look like this:

```
// convert to timestamp if necessary, remove if unneeded
$commentExpiry == strtotime($mainNews[0]['date_comments_expire']);

if ($mainNews[0]['allow_comments'] == 'Yes' AND 
    $commentExpiry > time()) {
  //submit comments
} else {
  //error handling
}
```

Comment: @JeffDavidson You mean it's a PHP DateTime object? In that case, you can use DateTime::getTimestamp() to get the Unix timestamp, and compare it as above. Basically, that part of the conditional becomes `$mainNews[0]['date_comments_expire']->getTimestamp() > time()`

Comment: @JeffDavidson Ok, so you're not using PHP DateTime objects. Can you show me exactly how `$mainNews[0]['date_comments_expire']` is generated? Is this a field you got from a database? If so, which database, and what is the data type of the field?

Comment: @JeffDavidson Right, but there is also a DateTime object in PHP, which is what confused me. I assume you're talking about the MySQL DATETIME datatype now, in which case `strtotime()` shouldn't have an issue with it, which is what I originally recommended. Did this give you an error? (I assumed by "what if it's a datetime format" that you meant the PHP DateTime, since the answer I had already given you would work on the MySQL version)